# Test Hibernate + Spring from public static void main

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm Spring and Hibernate newbie.
I've created the entity User and DAO - UserHibernateDao.
I want to test how the hibernate working in simple java-class with public static void main:

```
public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/org/jtalks/jcommune/model/entity/applicationContext-dao.xml");
    Dao<User> uhd = (Dao) context.getBean("userDao");
    User user = new User();
    user.setNickName("UserName");
    uhd.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

}

but I get the error

> INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@17b4703] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)

I understand I need to create something like session and transaction but I don't know how exactly I should do this.

[my config](https://github.com/Temdegon/jtalks/blob/master/jcommune/jcommune-model/src/main/resources/org/jtalks/jcommune/model/entity/applicationContext-dao.xml)
[User.java](https://github.com/Temdegon/jtalks/blob/master/jcommune/jcommune-model/src/main/java/org/jtalks/jcommune/model/entity/User.java)
[UserHibernateDao.java](https://github.com/Temdegon/jtalks/blob/master/jcommune/jcommune-model/src/main/java/org/jtalks/jcommune/model/dao/hibernate/UserHibernateDao.java)
[Full Project](https://github.com/Temdegon/jtalks)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the @Transactional annotation to your DAO's method.

That will initiate the transactional context.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public User getUser(int id) {
..
}
```

Comment: I think what @craftsman meant was that in order to test your code you shouldn't have to modify the code you want to test.  Instead, you would use something like JUnit to drive your real object so it's being tested the same way it would be tested in a real environment.  If so, that comment should have been directed at the original question, not your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you read this [reference on Spring and Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) as it will help you understand how to set this all up.